# Parametrize Vega or Vega-lite data url?

Tags: json, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite, vega

I am trying to create a Vega/Vega-lite data fetch based on a parameter/transform/signal defined later down in the chart specification. Is this possible? It would be of tremendous use with fetching data from parametric APIs.
E.g. instead of:

```
"data" : {"url" : "https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2021-12-04/fw48h"}
```

I would like:

```
"data" : {"url": "'https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/'+myDate+'/fw48h'"}
"transform": [ {"calculate": "'2021-12-04'", "as":"myDate"} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL can be specified as Vega signal expression. Assuming *myDate* is a named signal with valid string value, try:

```
"data" : {"url": {"signal": "'https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/' + myDate + '/fw48h'"},
          "transform": ...
          }
```

Here is an example of Vega tutorial
https://vega.github.io/vega/tutorials/airports/

with the part of url path for *traffic* data from a signal value.

[View in Vega on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aAJwAGNTPg0yWNAIBsmkDiQKFNcWTShMbHGgBMAmQBs4AM0xpjAJx16qMZMbNhsCD4AvjJIDHYQNABecGgg4hIpMglk4kiuEGgA2qC5CCnoCACeAKq+rgAKSMoyxHkM5SCUBApN-CDRJUhlqTBspL7SIK2u7WjiDK6uMhJFoHCk4pgF6AACUHCLqAhsDBBwY3ATMgw4PZgddwwRAyDrcJvbIHsHrkcnZydvNdbk0OvNFv0ALovUodTB0dyTaazdDVSgAZUoAAIAII0Xw4Ni+LZSLGODQADkmNzuHVG4yxAH4sfTLpRYViANRYgDkWIAFHzuazfKxelzeQBKPmoXlozG4-GE4kQUnktQUnn9KSDYbofaLAD6EEwvjYAGtMlM2uVwUsQCtUMVXhstqkFExXFBXDQoObqSD7qkDa5jaaLXAmVi7VjZTymGbZOItS83h9UsdTnAFGwkwBCAO04M-MNmy1QyKQmR3FBO3UdE2ggrXOru3oEU4AWgAjGoECIxJIZB4ichvKhbJUcHD7GxRCth3AmgxfA3ME3tSBTUhxBAR74InWt1OOmRzqZmiYzcI4FB4Y6r3Pb-fJJWYUM4b4kB4PL7qa2JxAbJclcDMajqRp6AlHkPB9XQtk7JAlSJTBKCgCBiBTYdRyaGxj2nYMMMmUxfDOVJYjsTdt13fdD2dTAT3IsgyFXCggxkFiThwJhKiKB1-FoSQqxAX8DgUbZChAKATk2EBhPsCSgKeOSYkU2CAjdaFoR1NIP3I5CVX-UD0BrAgkIJFCIDQojsIPXDAIYgj9RskwkFIjoKLYKivxo0dVnwjpXDYC0bkmDwzUPLcvx-P8ZEtXj0CJHRLDCmgxMUmhehUkAkEU7cYqgOSXkcjpf1ce4rleAAPHAJhM5d+3y38oCxPMAF5owWUDisY9Az1nSwgUfG873YSR0Fqp9RoXES0tccS+KCqw6AYBQrVcJoVrWoqdJK1IyoqyY4BquqQEefsqtajqYwAMhurFzsoSors6iEeqcqYiQkNgaEmKrUn+mQEpAXj3o6aTFmfSYxGJPDRPm1Imt9Sh1Pg5t+LW061ugd4LCsfo3x02FUjNOI4HRldjLO9tUawCBEIM1D0OIMKcPHScPuZ4i3LI9BPO8nc9z8o89vQA7LiOk6RguXwsTulkZbFdcsTajrHqSwTtQ5wLgvNULhwi-SLMMuK4GBzL11S9K+I1lLq3J+FchfbLcr4sQV32SZ118M9vG07X9pocqJZkY7arbTAnkod3fH2OX7se73fa1gLUh9cRzQvGBoZgJAPvTlI32EyaRpfCT61SEvnzGr3epy1wmEuCBqggFAsigPJym7dUZGoiANqDI9gLyVJ5CUGAsQIMkU+HqntHgyfp6L9vO-L3S9SApIrVFkAC7cyYc2QFLAJrRHouaq2EbFuC6c3HyzyKbsDCkXsNC0mRkF8c0153rOwsNk+WV0CNnuAUaIrxxDSW2oBd4h1AJlWMqAZEHQADEa10GFyyOGcsgFkGjxgHQQu4CaSgjwn-eBc0FCVyaNnSIdCwapAgJUBAIRQIG3CHhU+fNGZgNDpAtg0C1ibAloBBIyQ8LQE7owrel8qHoCRlAFGN83TgIQXhPBwD7gHE9LMVRQdXAAHlTBQDoAlJBNofCUApOAk0ZZyjmJmB0WQBCgw2OwXAAA6ooZQuCLGoG7JQAQdDgRFkAv9ChYkAabjMbNSJ6BQb0N2nXP+Mhib6h+P-DhgDLbcONiovhUD7EQLgaANRvjHFn0FiRWBm5bERi8ePdRfi1CUAAMxBOIYGIp5DSmUOocoNxdiJE6BAsWI0dTyz0IYRNGhkxBqXCQKNUgaAPB5DOOww8oAuEgFJqAzc7xCl4VgSI0APTYlX1cgMrBQzykohAJ6RZ-pBkRiMYs0xTSKlBDaR04JAd5HHSGvMr8SzyirPyHAApAiinHLqqAcJoBZ6j28dnZYP4zjjk7EEoGHyURqD0RCW5HQHl+k3COTY6IZGEqcHimIcFxoOLuQJPQwSQAkMHrYAFwycgj3kQiIhdDoRAA)

Comment: Thanks! This works in flawlessly in Vega - then it's probably a just a matter of a pull request to lift this up into the VL specification as well.